# Out of memory error when creating matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix

I tried to run a simple code that involves creating a big matrix, for example,

`A=zeros(5,factorial(5)^5)`

which is basically a 5 by 24883200000 matrix. Only to perform this, Matlab shows the 'out of memory error'.

What can I do if I really need to create this matrix? Increase the memory or break the matrix into parts?

The following is the memory in the terminal at the moment the code is paused:

> 2242  MATLAB       0.0  01:00.38 54    0    300   2731M  0B     62G
>   2242 1    sleeping *1[37]          0.00000

Comment: You can buy more RAM. Preferably a whole lot of it. It's a 995GB (so say 1TB) matrix (`5*24883200000*8` bytes), so that's the amount you're looking at

Comment: How you handle it depends on what operations you need to do. The only absolute solution is to buy more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with very big matrix, if almost all elements of this matrix are zero. It is special type of matrix - **sparse** matrix. See documentation - [matlab sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). Change your code:

```
A=sparse(5,factorial(5)^5);
```